# How to check with if an Oracle's view exist in the DB ? Before execute a query

Tags: java, database, oracle

I need to know a way to check from a Java Desktop App, if a Oracle's view exist in the current DB before execute a query otherwise I will get a lot of troubles...

thanks in advance

Comment: How will you get in "a lot of troubles"?

Comment: Why might you be querying a view that doesn't exist? Once it's there it's always there; unless you're creating it dynamically at execution, which isn't a great idea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always query the Oracle data dictionary.  Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM all_views
 WHERE view_name = <<the name of the view>>
   AND owner     = <<the owner of the view>>
```

will tell you whether you have access to a view owned by the specified user with the specified name.

Alternately, you can use a more Java-centric approach.  You can create a [`DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) object from your `Connection` and call `getTables` to get a list of all the tables and views that you have access to.  You can pass `getTables` a specific table or view name (or a pattern) to restrict the results.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM user_views
WHERE view_name = 'MY_VIEW'
```

More details in the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5499.htm#i1635848

Comment: Only if the view is owned by the current schema.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: that's what most of the people want to see. At least the OP did not state that the view should be searched regardless of the owner. Btw: user_views shows the views owned by the current owner, not the current schema. Which - despite an owner an schema are very similar - is not the same thing.

Comment: thanks, you're right, I should have said current owner. However, it's very common for applications to log in using an owner/schema that owns no objects, because of the security issues this entails, so all_views would make more sense for the stated requirement (query access).

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: well, without MadMad666 clarifying how it's done in his/her application we'll never know

Answer (score 1):

In case you want see not only if view exist and if view enable for current user but if view VALID or INVALID you can use select from all_objects table

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM all_objects t
WHERE 
t.object_type = 'VIEW' 
and t.object_name = 'VIEW_NAME'
and t.status = 'VALID'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone, finally I got a method that solves this issue, thanks for your suggestions, the code is the following:

```
    public boolean existViewInDB(String viewName) {
    logger.debug("[boolean existViewInDB(String viewName[" + viewName
        + "])]");
    boolean existView = false;
    try {
        String sql =
            "SELECT count(*) FROM user_views WHERE view_name = :viewName";
        SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setString("viewName", viewName);
        BigDecimal totalOfViews = (BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
        existView = (totalOfViews.longValue() > 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
    }
    logger.debug("Exist View [" + viewName + "] ? -> " + existView);
    return existView;
}
```

This works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time check I'd say it's fine, but if you perform a query on that view repeatedly I'd say it's a bad idea to check again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use user_views for all views owned by you or ALL_VIEWS for all the views you have access to. I would use all_views

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ALL_VIEWS
WHERE VIEW_NAME = '[YOUR VIEW NAME']
```

Comment: When using `ALL_VIEWS` you should also add a condition on the owner of the view. Otherwise you might get a "positive" result but still can't access the view without qualifying the owner.

Comment: Also the last line should be: `WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'YOUR VIEW NAME HERE'`
 
No brackets needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just query it. If it doesn't exist, or your session doesn't have the necessary privileges, Oracle will raise a suitable exception.