# How to check if view exists in java?

Tags: java, sql

```
DatabaseMetaData dbm = connection.getMetaData(); // connection is of type Connection (in JDBC)  
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "table name", null); // check if table is there
if (tables.next()) {
    //Table exists
} else {
    //Table does not exist
}
```

My question is how to check if the view exists. The above code is how to check if the table exist. I know it is similar to the above code but I'm having trouble.

Comment: please check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10174709/957654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getTables()` method can return all types of tables (where a view is considered a type of a table). The last parameter can be used to search for specific type(s).

In your case you could use `dbm.getTables(null, null, "viewname", new String[]{"VIEW"});`. The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) explain this very well, so you should be reading them before you ask here.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that table names were written in java code with camel case which caused an issue when checking if a table existed - but it worked fine with dropping and creating. So what I did was simply

```
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "table name".toLowerCase(), null);
```